# Char to Int conversion in c

Tags: c, char, int

How can I convert a char to Int?

This is what I have done so far.

Thanks

```
scanf("%s", str );

printf("str: %s\n", str);

int i;
if(isdigit(*str))
    i = (int) str;
else {
    i = 3;
}
```

test case

```
7
str: 7
i: 1606415584
```

Comment: Instead of `i = (int) str;` that is wrong, try `sscanf(str,"%d",&i);`

Comment: its a c code why have you tagged it as a c++ code

Comment: @desprado07 - don't be so anal :)  It wasn't at all "wrong" to tag this as C++ (but it's obviously better to change it to "C", as the OP apparently did).  Cut him some slack, OK ;)?

Comment: @desprado07 Actually this is valid C++ code although it does fit C more closely. Edit: What paulsm4 said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parse an integer from a string:

```
i = atoi(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: I could have sworn the post was tagged C++ at the start. I'll leave this up in case the OP is interested in C++ answers and the change to C tag was an edit.**

A further option, which may be advanced given the question, is to use [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) as so:

```
scanf("%s", str );

printf("str: %s\n", str);

int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>( str );
```

I have used boost::lexical_cast a lot to convert between types, mostly strings and primitives when reading in user-defined properties. I find it an invaluable resource.

It's worth noting that boost::lexical_cast can throw exceptions, and these should be appropriately handled when you use the call. The link I posted at the start of this answer contains all the information you should need regarding that.

Comment: +1 for the sake of **C++** && for mentioning the exception-handling of `boost::lexical_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing the character and string concepts here.  `str` is a string, and `str[0]` (which is equivalent to `*str`) is a character, the first character of that string.

If you want to extract an integer from the string, try this

```
sscanf(str,"%d",&i);
```

Your

```
i = (int) str;
```

forces 4 bytes that start at the same memory address str (and for completeness sake, str is a pointer) starts to be interpreted as an integer, and that's why you get a result that's totally off.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert strings to int by using `sscanf`

```
sscanf(str,"%d",&i);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

Answer (score 1):

```
i = (int) str;
```

is a wrong way to convert a string to number, because It copies an **address** to `i` variable (the address which `str` is pointing to it).

You could try this:

```
i = atoi(str);
```

or

```
sscanf(str,"%d",&i);
```

to convert your string into a number.

Note that you cannot make sure the entered string is numeric by just `isdigit(*str)`, because it only check the first character of the string.

One possible way is this:

```
int isNumeric = 1;
for(int j=0;j<length(str);j++)
   if( isdigit(str[j]) == false)
   {
      isNumeric = 0;
      break;
   }

if(isNumeric)
{
   // Code when the string is number 
   // (e.g. convert the string to a number with atoi function)
}
else
{
   // Code when the string is NOT number 
   // (e.g. show a error message)
}
```